# React-Native: Rendering of images is not consistent

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am using an API to get the image urls. I am able to fetch the image urls properly. But sometime few images are not rendering.

Is there any issue in react-native codes ?

```
var productDetail = this.state.result[i];
this.state.product.push(
  <View key = {i}  style={{margin: 0.5, borderWidth: 10, borderColor: 'white', backgroundColor: 'white'}}>
    <Image
      resizeMode={'contain'}
      style={{width: width/2.35, height: 180,}}
      source={{uri: "https://abcd.in"+productDetail.image_url}}>
    </Image>
  </View>
```

rendering like:

```
<View>
    {product}
</View>
```

Comment: Dont mutate state directly it doesn't cause a rerender, use setState see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41376203/why-cant-i-push-values-in-my-state-array-in-react-js/41376329#41376329

Comment: As @ShubhamKhatri said, the issue is because of your way of updating your app. You shouldn't mutate the state, instead you should use setState that also triggers a re-render. This is why the behaviour is inconsistent.

Comment: To expand on my previous comment you would have:

`addProduct = () => {
    this.setState({
        product: product.concat(
            <View key = {i}  style={{margin: 0.5, borderWidth: 10, borderColor: 'white', backgroundColor: 'white'}}>
                <Image
                  resizeMode={'contain'}
                  style={{width: width/2.35, height: 180,}}
                  source={{uri: "https://abcd.in"+productDetail.image_url}}>
                </Image>
              </View>
        )
    });
  }`

Answer (score 0):

Updated Answer:

```
var productDetail = this.state.result[i];
var products = this.state.product.slice();

products.push(
    <View key = {i}  style={{margin: 0.5, borderWidth: 10, borderColor: 'white', backgroundColor: 'white'}}>
        <Image
            resizeMode={'contain'}
                style={{width: width/2.35, height: 180,}}
                source={{uri: "https://abcd.in"+productDetail.image_url}}>
        </Image>
    </View>)

this.setState({
    product: products
})
```

Comment: That is definitely not the issue, check [the documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/image.html).

Comment: By doing this I am getting this error: Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within `render` or another component's constructor). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state; constructor side-effects are an anti-pattern, but can be moved to `componentWillMount`.

Comment: update the state in `componentDidMount` or `componentWillReceiveProps`.