# React , create history state based on array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i learn this simple tic tac toe game in react based on official article here[here](https://codepen.io/gaearon/pen/gWWZgR?editors=0010)

instead i learn step by step from that 100% i prefer to build with my own way,
everything ok (ignore about effectiveness code i still learn) after i need to add history feature based from state and i cant use

```
array.push
```

for state in react based on here [Why can't I push values in my state array in react.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41376203/why-cant-i-push-values-in-my-state-array-in-react-js)

and use `array.concat` instead, and you know i expect array value is contain difference game state value, **but i got same game state from first array in to the end instead but if i hard code that state only first game state got is difference [here array result example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5px2R.png)**

and here my result from now [here my tictactoe](https://jsfiddle.net/tendif/6tdxpmnL/10/)

Comment: your gameHistory is an array of objects, and you concat an array into it?

Comment: sorry my mistake, i replace that picture  and my tictactoe link with new one. but the result still same if you do not mind u can see new picture above